# Retrofit Form Data

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am trying to hit an endpoint that requires form data and with post man i can get a 200 with the following, note I've replaced the url with `/url`, the api key with `key`, the host with `host` and the referrer with `referrer` but they are accurate and match in both cases.

When look at the code generated by postman I see

```
POST /url?api_key=key HTTP/1.1
Host: host
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Referer: referrer
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 00ad8c82-be8a-4c0d-a79b-fd7e3e941430

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="user[first_name]"

first

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="user[last_name]"

last

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="user[email]"

flast@gmail.com

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="user[terms_and_conditions]"

1
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

However with retrofit I keep getting a 422 and the request looks like this from stetho

```
Request URL: /url?api_key=key
Request Method:POST
Request Headers
Provisional headers are shown
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:563
Content-Type:multipart/form-data;
Host: host
Referer: referrer
User-Agent:okhttp/3.10.0
Query String Parameters
api_key: key
Request Payload
--b9048dea-56eb-4fad-8436-b1d70b753bb1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="user[first_name]"
Content-Length: 5

first
--b9048dea-56eb-4fad-8436-b1d70b753bb1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="user[last_name]"
Content-Length: 4

last
--b9048dea-56eb-4fad-8436-b1d70b753bb1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="user[email]"
Content-Length: 15

flast@gmail.com 
--b9048dea-56eb-4fad-8436-b1d70b753bb1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="user[terms_and_conditions]"
Content-Length: 1

1
--b9048dea-56eb-4fad-8436-b1d70b753bb1--
```

I have tried to use a multipart request body

```
@POST("/url")
  @Headers(
    "Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
    "Content-Type: multipart/form-data;",
    "Referer: referrer"
  )
  fun signUp(
    @Query("api_key") apiKey: String,
    @Body requestBody : RequestBody
  ): Single<NetworkResponse<AuthResponse, Error>>
```

I have also tried to use an @PartMap (with the same headers)

```
@Multipart
  fun signUp(
    @Query("api_key") apiKey: String,
    @PartMap map: Map<String, String>
  ): Single<NetworkResponse<AuthResponse, Error>>
```

Finally I have tried to use multiple @Part fields in the service (with the same headers)

```
@Multipart
  fun signUp(
    @Query("api_key") apiKey: String,
    @Part("user[first_name") firstName: RequestBody,
    @Part("user[first_name") lastName: RequestBody,
    @Part("user[first_name") email: RequestBody,
    @Part("user[first_name") toc: RequestBody
  ): Single<NetworkResponse<AuthResponse, Error>>
```

None of these options seem to work or give me the same result as Postman.  The differences I can see are that the parts have a content-length with retrofit and that there are these random string separators between.

I don't own the api so I cannot change it.

**Edit** I removed the Content-Length as described in the answer below and I still get a 422.  The output now looks like this with the same headers.  So it seems the last remaining difference is those random strings

```
--5d70bd2c-10e7-4444-84bc-aab7cb3e86ee
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="user[first_name]"

Zachary 
--5d70bd2c-10e7-4444-84bc-aab7cb3e86ee
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="user[last_name]"

sweigart
--5d70bd2c-10e7-4444-84bc-aab7cb3e86ee
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="user[email]"

zsweigart@gmail.com 
--5d70bd2c-10e7-4444-84bc-aab7cb3e86ee
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="user[terms_and_conditions]"

1
--5d70bd2c-10e7-4444-84bc-aab7cb3e86ee--
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you. [Workaround how to remove content-length.](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2604)

Comment: So I tried commenting out like the workaround says and I got the expected output but now I get an error `java.net.ProtocolException: expected 446 bytes but received 486`

Comment: Ahh actually I see what I did and fixing it I still get a 422